# How to get decrypted transaction data in quorum?

Tags: transactions, quorum, encryption

On **Quorum_Node1** I am sending a transaction with `privateFor:` parameter as follows:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: "0xca84356...9a3d0ccf92b8e", 
data: web3.toHex('sample message for node 2'),privateFor:
['QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=']})
```

Where `QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=` is a public key of Transaction Manager on **Quorum Node2**

When I try to get the transaction data on **Quorum Node2** via:

```
eth.getTransaction("0x26a550c39b816...97c6f6eb35c3953e53b7")
```

I am getting an encrypted payload. Ideally, I should receive hex representation of the data sent in the original transaction.

Is this possible in Quorum or it works just with contracts?

Comment: Quorum uses the regular eth transaction to send an encrypted payload hash (you found it) and an additional P2P layer (Constellation or Tessera) to send encrypted transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so as pointed out in comments, when you read the transaction on any node, you receive the encrypted hash of the transaction and not the actual payload. To access the payload, you would run [this api](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/docs/api.md#eth_getquorumpayload) on node 2.